# Solving a compound inequality

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

I am getting a bit turned around by the following inequality.

x+5 <= x+1 <= 6

I believe there is no solution.

Comment: Hint: just consider the left piece. Something looks sus...

Comment: Since $5>1,$ we always have $x+5>\dots$

Answer (score 2):

As you point out, there is no solution. If we have a real number $x$ such that $x+5\leq x+1\leq 6$ then of course $x+5\leq x+1$ and after substracting $x$ from both sides we obtain $5\leq 1$ which is an absurdity.